# Installing Lizmap Web Client on Windows - demo project don't appear

Tags: lizmap

I followed the protocol from the url bellow*, in order to install Lizmap Web Client on Windows, but demo project don't appear.

What could be the problem?

*https://opengislab.com/blog/2018/7/7/updated-installing-apache-qgis-server-and-lizmap-on-windows-os

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to test Lizmap Web Client in Windows you should use the [Vagrant installation](https://github.com/3liz/lizmap-web-client/tree/master/vagrant). If you are happy with what you see then you should use Linux for production, it is the recommended way to use LWC.

Comment: Hello, hello Nicolas Boisteault,
I uninstalled and reinstalled, having succeeded, in windows 10.
I'll follow the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Add .exe on your wms URL. I know this problem